# How to make a foreign key not using primary key

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relation, laravel-migrations

I have a migration on Laravel for table pasien like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pasien', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('No_RM');
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->primary('No_RM');
    });
}
```

and now I want to make a foreign key to No_RM , **NOT** to **id**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('data_primary', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unique('RM_id');
        $table->string('file_primary');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('RM_id')->references('No_RM')->on('pasien');
    });
}
```

and still have error

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `file_primary` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp ' at line 1")

Can someone correct my error?

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another migration to modify your `pasien` table like

```
Schema::table('pasien', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unique('RM_id');
});
```

and now you can declare `RM_id` as foreign key in `data_primary`, table, to becoming a foreign key, it should unique key.

If you have dropped your migrations, you are creating new tables you can do it like

**pasien table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pasien', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('No_RM')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and **data_primary** table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('data_primary', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('RM_id');
        $table->string('file_primary');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('RM_id')->references('RM_id')->on('pasien')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: and On Table parent i changed this string to BigIncrements sir ?

Comment: @AdhikMulat you do not need to, for example `email_id` can be a `unique` column and can be a `foreign key` in another table.

Comment: @AdhikMulat you are making it wrong dear, if you have already created tables, you should use a new migration to modify the `pasien` table to make the `RM_id` unique and if you have rolledback your migrations you just need to add `$table->unique('RM_id');` your `pasien` table and specify `RM_id` as foreign key in reference with `pasien` table.

Comment: hmmm i really dont get it . See on this table 'Pasien' i add string to type data . is this true for foreign type : "unique'

Comment: look if you are using laravel 5.8 you need to use bigincrements for the primary key and unsignedBigInteger for the foreign key https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: @AhmedAboud that is an example can you identify where it has said, you are bould to use `unsignedBigInteger ` in parent table?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26472 and  if the parent table id is bigIncrements the reference key must be same type unsignedBigInteger

Comment: @AhmedAboud to make foreign key, you only need the column to be unique in parent table see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: oh after 2nd check he is using a string as a reference iam so sorry

Answer (score -1):

Conceptually you cant reference foreign key to a non primary key, it breaks the concept of relational database, can you provide me the ERD maybe i can help to redesign your DB structure